# Getting Application Error after deployment, I am getting the following error in the screen shots below

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2][image]

I added procfile and checked if there are any folder naming issues. But still I am getting this error. Please help me with this.

Also I just noticed that I am getting the following error when I tried to run locally.

Comment: Please add error message as text https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I tried to run application locally in my computer and I got this module not found error. I installed express several times and same error is repeating. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting the server using `npm start`, if the `users` is a file as in a javascript react file then capitalize its name and make it `Users.js` and it says it can't find the module that you are trying to import so make sure you are not pointing to a folder

Comment: Front-End React JS part is working correctly. But backend nodejs is crashing. I am getting the module not found error

Comment: My issue has been resolved. Instead of using "Routes" folder,  I was using "routes" which caused the issue. It rectified the issue.